# Images with a wave in Zurb's Foundation columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, zurb-foundation

For a WordPress website I'm working with the CSS framework Foundation 6. 
The design has a row that contains 2 large-6 columns. Each column is filled with an image. However these images have a wave shape on the inside. See the image I attached.

[The row with 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0bqC.jpg)

Now I've created 2 columns with images inside, but my problem is I can't get those 2 images to "touch" each other as in the image I've shared.
See pen: https://codepen.io/Jerryschouwink/pen/MmVeQL

```
<div class="row expanded collapse">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <img src="http://projecten.webinc.nl/pen/img-left.png">
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <img src="http://projecten.webinc.nl/pen/img-right.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there someone who can tell me how to do this?

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the image a class and add negative margin to it.

```
.right{
  margin-left: -35px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/PmRGPB

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately that is no the solution I'm looking for. That just moves my image to the center, but I still need it to stick to the side of the screen.